# Changing XenServer from LVM SR to EXT SR

Tags: lvm, xenserver, openstack

I'm trying to setup openstack using this page: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/XenServer/PostInstall

Unfortunately I think when I setup xenserver it setup the local SR as LVM (which the page above says limits what openstack can do). The link on the page to convert LVM to EXT is broken.

How can I convert LVM to EXT or am I better just to do a clean install?

Comment: I would do a clean install if the server isn't in production. I'm running XenServer for almost an year now (since it became opensource) and the most problematic things in XenServer are the SR architecture.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Easier in the long run

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of storage your server is using.  If the setup is already completed and you are using only local SR. you can not convert the format of the disk without reinstalling Xen on the drive. if you do have additional drives, simply fdisk the drive as ext3  (makefs.ext3) then create an SR to use as default.

`xe sr-create content-type="Local SR" host-uuid=(press tab to enter it automatically) type=ext device-config-device=/dev/sda(DeviceNumberGoesHere) shared=false name-label="Local File SR"`

If you do a clean install of Xen, make sure to choose thin provisioning for XenDesktop. This will default your storage format to ext3 
“Important: Thin Provisioning changes the default local storage type of the host from LVM to EXT3”
http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/32308-102-691301/installation.pdf
Chapter 5. XenServer and IntelliCache

in your nova.conf set the storage to use the default